# Laravel - Filter collection with where and wildcard

Tags: arrays, laravel, filter, filtering, laravel-collection

I would like to filter an array, to get a collection that only contains services where `enabled` = `true` (by either inclusion or exclusion).

I don't want to uses nested `filter()`, or anything too verbose.

The array looks like:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [services] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [vat] => 20
                            [enabled] => false
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [vat] => 20
                            [enabled] => true
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 27
                            [vat] => 20
                            [enabled] => false
                        )

                    ...
```

Here is what I tried:

```php
collect($myArray)->where('services.*.enabled', '=', true)->each(...
```

But the return of this `where` statement is an empty collection.

Is there a way to achieve that result?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "*Is there a way to achieve that result?*" - Yes, nested `->filter()` functions. *"I don't want to uses nested filter()"* - Any particular reason?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `whereHas()` when querying these from the database, that is assuming they are A) stored in a database and B) have relationships setup.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for your response. Yes, I feel like nested `filter()` would be hard to read and maintain. If there's no better way, I'd prefer to stick with basic foreach loops.

Comment: @TimLewis Unfortunately, this array doesn't come from a relationship but from a FormRequest `validated` array.

Comment: No worries! I figured it wasn't a database call, all good  And I don't think it would be too hard to read. `->filter(function ($item) { return collect($item['services'])->filter(function ($service) { return $service['enabled']; })->isNotEmpty(); });` (it's hard to read as a comment, but that's a Stackoverflow issue). You can use `foreach()` if you'd like too, but yeah, long answer short is that a wildcard `services.*.enabled` won't work here. Screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jnLN.png

Comment: I think `contains` instead of `filter(...)->isNotEmpty()` could be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```php
collect($yourArray)
    ->filter(function ($item) {
        return collect($item['services'])->contains('enabled', true);
    })
```

[`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-contains) returns a boolean so you can use it as the return value of [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-filter).

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the collection is not filtered. I tried messing around a with the contains method, but I got nothing from it. 

Ex: 
`collect($myArray)->filter(function ($item) {
     return collect($item)->contains('services.*.enabled');
 })`

Comment: `contains` doesn't like that. Check the documentation.